# Migrate MySQL 5.7 to 8.0 via mysqldump

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysqldump, mysql-8.0

I have an Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS with MySQLl 5.7

I have new Ubuntu backup server 20.04 LTS with MySQL 8.0

MySQL 5.7 backup created:

```
mysqldump --all-databases > "filename" -u root -p
```

Restore to 8.0 fails on MySQL database due to ISAM tables.

Restoring individual databases, except MySQL, works as expected.

Once I have an 8.0 backup I'll upgrade the 18.04 server to 20.04 with MySQL 8.0

Is it possible to modify the MySQL 5.7 dump to load on 8.0?

Answer (score 3):

## Recreate the dump from MySQL 5.7

Personally, I would recreate the dump without `mysql` schema.

```
SQL="SET group_concat_max_len = 1024 * 1024;"
SQL="${SQL} SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(schema_name separator ' ')"
SQL="${SQL} FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name NOT IN"
SQL="${SQL} ('information_schema','performance_schema','mysql','sys')"
DBLIST=`mysql -u... -p... -AN -e"${SQL}"`
mysqldump -u... -p... -B ${DBLIST} > mydbs.sql
```

Then, you can load `mydbs.sql` in the MySQL 8.0 instance.

## What about the dump you already have ?

First, find out the lines in the dump where each database starts and the number of line in the dump

```
grep -in "^USE" mydbs.sql
wc -l < mydbs.sql
```

As an example, I created a dump from a MySQL 5.7 vagrant instance.

```
root@LAPTOP-57FSQ99U:~# grep -in "^USE" mydbs.sql
24:USE `DMP492`;
122:USE `DMP551`;
190:USE `DMP579`;
228:USE `abeersul`;
262:USE `dbname`;
292:USE `karma`;
300:USE `mysql`;
1212:USE `pch_prod`;
1220:USE `pchcom_prod`;
1286:USE `tryout`;
root@LAPTOP-57FSQ99U:~# wc -l < mydbs.sql
1341
root@LAPTOP-57FSQ99U:~#
```

Next, create a new dump. Copy everything above and below the `mysql` schema

In this case, everything before line 300

Then, copy everything from the first DB after `mysql` schema

In this case, subtract 1212 (first line of the next DB after the `mysql` schema) from 1341 (the number of lines in the original dump you made) and add 1. Then copy that number of lines from the bottom of the original dump into the new dump:

```
head -299 mydbs.sql > newdump.sql
(( LINES = 1341 - 1212 + 1 ))
tail -${LINES} mydbs.sql >> newdump.sql
```

As a demonstration, note how the new dump will not have the `mysql` schema

```
root@LAPTOP-57FSQ99U:~# head -299 mydbs.sql > newdump.sql
root@LAPTOP-57FSQ99U:~# (( LINES = 1341 - 1212 + 1 ))
root@LAPTOP-57FSQ99U:~# tail -${LINES} mydbs.sql >> newdump.sql
root@LAPTOP-57FSQ99U:~# grep -in "^USE" newdump.sql
24:USE `DMP492`;
122:USE `DMP551`;
190:USE `DMP579`;
228:USE `abeersul`;
262:USE `dbname`;
292:USE `karma`;
300:USE `pch_prod`;
308:USE `pchcom_prod`;
374:USE `tryout`;
root@LAPTOP-57FSQ99U:~#
```

Now, just load newdump.sql into MySQL 8.0

Comment: To clarify, when I've completed the restore I'll have to create users inMYSQL8.0 to match the original users in the MYSQL5.7 database?